# concept of virtual functions in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, function

I read so many blogs and I understand how to use virtual function in c++. But, still I don't understand why we use virtual functions. Can you give me a real world example so that I can more easily visualize the actual meaning of virtual function.

Comment: do you have other oop background?

Comment: yes, I know java basic concepts.

Comment: They actually give an example on Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

Comment: @algoh If you know java, it is easy.  C++ function cannot be overridden by default. If you want the java-like behavior, youd make it `virtual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important thing to mention is that inheritance (which the keyword virtual is fundamental for) should not be for the sole purpose of code re-use, use delegation for this.

Delegation would be when we have a class say BroadbandConnection with a method called connection(). Then your manager says we want to add encryption, so you create a class BroadbandConnectionWithEncryption. Your natural instinct may be to use inheritance and then make the new class BroadbandConnectionWithEncryption derive from BroadbandConnection.

Drawback's to this is that the creator of the initial class had not designed it for inheritance so you would need to change its definition to make the method connection() virtual so you can override its behavior in the derived class. This is not always ideal. A better idea is to use delegation here for the purpose of code reuse.

```
class BroadBandConnection
{
public:
    void Connection (string password)
    {
        //connection code.
    }
};

class BroadBandConnectionWithEndcryption
{
public:
    void Connection (string password)
    {
        mbroadbandconnection.Connection(password);
        //now do some stuff to zero the memory or
        //do some encryption stuff
    }

private:
    BroadBandConnection mbroadbandconnection;
};
```

The keyword virtual is used for the purpose of polymorphism. As the name suggest, it is the ability for an object to have more than one form. This sort of decision would be made at the time of designing an interface or class.

```
class IShape
{
    virtual void Draw () = 0; 
};

class Square
{
    void Draw()
    {
        //draw square on screen 
    }
};

class Circle
{
    void Draw()
    {
        //draw circle on screen
    }
};
```

I made Draw() pure virtual with the = 0. I could have left this out and added some default implementation. Pure virtual makes sense for Interfaces where there is no reasonable default implementation.

What this lets me do is pass around a Shape object to various methods and they do not need to be concerned with what I have just given them. All they know is that I have to provide something that supports the ability for a shape to draw itself.

```
IShape* circle = new Circle ();
IShape* square = new Square ();

void SomeMethod (IShape* someShape)
{
   someShape->Draw(); //This will call the correct functionality of draw
}
```

In the future as people begin thinking of new shapes, they can derive from IShape and so long as they implement some functionality for Draw. They can pass this object to SomeMethod.

Answer (score 1):

First, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/134609#134609).

Now, a real life example. I have a program with a GUI with three tabs. Each tab is an object of a class that derives from a common base, TabBase. It has a virtual function OnActivate(). When a tab is activated, the dispatcher calls it on the current tab. There's some common action and there are actions that are specific to this tab. This is implemented via virtual functions.

The benefit is that the controller does not need to know what kind of tab it is. It stores an array of TabBase pointers, and just calls OnActivate() on them. The magic of virtual functions makes sure the right override is called.

```
class TabBase
{
    virtual void OnActivate()
    {
    //Do something...
    }
};

class SearchTab: public TabBase
{
    void OnActivate() //An override
    {
        TabBase::OnActivate(); //Still need the basic setup
        //And then set up the things that are specific to the search tab
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use inheritance for this? Why wouldn't the Tab class have an `Activate` *event* and a specific instance, `searchTab`, would have a bound event handler. Seems like the animal example better demonstrates virtual methods, whereas the notion of different tabs is a good example of delegation.

Comment: There's no builtin notion of events in C++. Rolling your own is possible, but rather clunky.

Answer (score 0):

We have one base class (animal) that have method, that can be implemented differently by it's children (say). When we declare this method virtual, we can adress that method and it will be implemented from it's children's definition. You don't have to use virtual if you adress children's overloaded methods, but you have to, when you adress parent's methods.

For example, if you have a vector of animals each one of whom is different. You declare method (say) as virtual and call it from animal class and it will be called from corresponding child.

Correct me if I'm wrong, that's how I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

They actually give an example on Wiki

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

using animals.  Animals is the super class, all animals eat (the superclass virtual function).  Each animal may eat differently than all the other animals (overriding the virtual function).  I have a list of arbitrary animals, and when I call the eat function, they will display their own differing eating habit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Java - that should be easy. In Java, ALL class methods are effectively virtual. If you override it in a derived class, and you call it via a base class reference, the override will be called, not the base.

That's not the default behavior in C++. If you want a function to behave in that way, you have to declare it as virtual in the base class. Easy enough.

Java is choke full of virtual functions. It just does not have an explicit keyword for them.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of virtual functions is to achieve [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).

You say you are familiar with Java, so then for a real world use of virtual functions, think of any place in Java where you would have used an `interface` or used `@Override` on a public/protected method.

Answer (score 0):

The decision to use virtual functions is a simple matter. You just need to know when you'd want to override a base method. Take the following code as an example:

```
  class animal
 {
   public:
 void sound()
 {
  cout << "nothing";
 }
};
class bird : public animal
{
 public:
void sound()
{
cout << "tweet";
}
```

};

In this case, I'd want to override bird(). But what if I didn't? This is what would happen:

```
animal * a = new bird;
a->sound();
 **Output**
nothing
```

The screen would say nothing because for all intents and purposes, C++ only sees an animal. However, if you declared it virtual, it knows to search for the lowest method in the class hierachy. Try it again:

```
 class animal{
   public:
    virtual void sound(){cout<<"nothing";}
  };
 class bird : public animal
 {
    public:
   void sound()
    {
      cout << "tweet";
    }
  };
   animal * a = new bird;
  a->sound();
 **Output**
   tweet.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using a single-letters for class names that skips over the letter that the overridden method is called, is confusing. C is an A with a different B? why not a simple B is an A with an overriden doSomething() method?

Comment: @Doug I have edited it.Now I believe ,it would be clear to you.Thanks